# Azure Resource manager .Net API fails to get Resource group

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am trying to write a standalone program to access Azure Resource group details using Azure resource manager .Net library. As the per the documentation it requires Azure AD authentication and token in every resource manager request. So i created a web app in AD and configured secret key and using it to generate token.

But below code is failing even though I pass this token as bearer in request.

```
m_resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(connection.GetCredentials());
m_resourceClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new     AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", connection.GetAccessToken());
***ResourceGroupGetResult resourceGroupList = m_resourceClient.ResourceGroups.Get("PraveenTest")*** ;
```

Error message:

```
AuthorizationFailed: The client '5919f7f9-####-####-####-074456eba98c' with object id '5919f7f9-####-####-####-074456eba98c' does not have authorization to perform action 
'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/1f94c869-####-####-####-055e8ae15be3/resourcegroups/TestGroup'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bearer token is valid, but you also need to grant your application access to the resource group.

You can do this with the following PowerShell command:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment 
   -ObjectId '5919f7f9-####-####-####-074456eba98c' `
   -ResourceGroupName TestGroup `
   -RoleDefinitionName Reader
```

If you're using an Azure PowerShell version < 1.0, then the cmdlet is `New-AzureRoleAssignment`.

I'd recommend [Dushyant Gill's blog post](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2015/05/23/developers-guide-to-auth-with-azure-resource-manager-api/) on authenticating ARM requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot BenV. I am new to Azure. Your suggestion has resolved the issue.

Comment: I tried this, but when I execute this command I am getting the same error again in the prompt.

Comment: An update: In MS Azure Powershell version 1.0.1, New-AzureRoleAssignment is now New-AzureRmRoleAssignment

Comment: Saved my day!!
Tried the same in Azure portal didn't work. With PowerShell was no proplem

Comment: What is the object id actually ?

Comment: @user1142317 It's the object ID of the service principal of your application.